# can we define a variable before calling pthread-create() function

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthread-join

i try to test multithreading in c language and on Manjaro OS.
i write a small code but i faced a strange problem

i execute below simple code but i didn't get expected result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define THREADS 4

void *routine1(void * x)
{
    int result =2;
    pthread_exit((void *)result);
}

int main ()
{
    int sum=0;
    int retval=0;
   pthread_t threads[THREADS];
    for ( int i=0;i<THREADS;i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, routine1, (void *)i );
   for (int i=0; i<THREADS; i++)
   {
     pthread_join(threads[i],&retval);
     sum+=retval;
   }
   printf("%d\n",sum);
   return 0;
```

}

the result of above code is:

```
2
```

but i expected to see 8 value on output. after debugging for some hours i found that if i declare the sum variable after pthread_create() function, the code will run normally:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define THREADS 4

void *routine1(void * x)
{
    int result =2;
    pthread_exit((void *)result);
}

int main ()
{
    int retval=0;
   pthread_t threads[THREADS];
   for ( int i=0;i<THREADS;i++)
   pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, routine1, (void *)i );
   int sum=0;
   for (int i=0; i<THREADS; i++)
   {
        pthread_join(threads[i],&retval);
        sum+=retval;
   }
   printf("%d\n",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

the output of code is:

```
 8
```

which is right answer.

i want to know why the first code is wrong? it is because of pthread_create() function?

NOTE: if you run this code don't care about warnings, they are all about casting

Comment: ignore warnings at your peril.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's *not* the order. It's the *type* of `retval`. When, passing `&retval` to `pthread_join`, it's the wrong type/sizeof.

When `retval` is an `int`, it's only 4 bytes, but [assuming 64 bit compile], `pthread_join` expects a pointer to `void *`, which is 8 bytes.

This causes undefined behavior because the call will write 8 bytes into a variable that is only 4 bytes. The remaining 4 bytes go beyond the size of `retval` and may overwrite *anything* on the stack.

There was the same undefined behavior in your second example, but we just "got lucky" and got the expected result [probably because the order of variables in the stack frame changed to avoid the UB from producing an unexpected result]. But, both still had UB.

Also, when casting to/from a pointer, we should use `long` instead of `int` [to prevent compiler warnings].

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define THREADS 4

void *
routine1(void *x)
{
#if 0
    int result = 2;
#else
    long result = 2;
#endif

    pthread_exit((void *) result);
}

int
main()
{
    int sum = 0;
#if 0
    int retval = 0;
#else
    void *retval;
#endif
    pthread_t threads[THREADS];

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, routine1, (void *) i);
#else
    for (long i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, routine1, (void *) i);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], &retval);
#if 0
        sum += retval;
#else
        sum += (long) retval;
#endif
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: sir, even usage of long doesn't cause ub?

Comment: @snr No, using `long` prevents the warning _cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]_. Here, it doesn't matter much, but in the general case, casting a pointer to an int can/will chop off the high 32 bits, so if they're non-zero, the resulting value is truncated. Not UB, just a wrong value.

Comment: No, we should use `uintptr_t`. `long` isn't guaranteed to be the size of a pointe.

Comment: @JL2210 This is actually dictated by the architecture. See: http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html and look at the table. That's the spec that all modern arches adhere to and were designed around. `long` is fine for all models except `LLP64` and _only_ MS/Win* uses that one [And, I don't do windows ;-)]. Virtually all others use `LP64` [with `long long` being 64].